# How to read cookies with Microsoft.AspNet (DNX)

Tags: cookies, dnx

with plain old ASP.NET reading a cookie was as easy as getting hold of the `HttpContext.Current.Request` object, but in DNX there is no such object.

How does one check for a cookie value in order to change it's the response?

```
public static string GetContentValueByKey(this Dictionary<string, string> content, string key) {
    string value;
    return content.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : key;
}
```

I want now, based on a cookie value, return only the `key` instead the `value`... in the "old good days" I could easily do:

```
public static string GetContentValueByKey(this Dictionary<string, string> content, string key) {
    string value;
    var cookies = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies;
    var showKeysOnly = cookies["showonlykeys"] != null && cookies["showonlykeys"] == "yes";
    return showKeysOnly ? key : content.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : key;
}
```

but we no longer have access to such object ... what is the trick to access the Cookies outside a Controller?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core there is no thing as a static `HttpContext.Current`. You either need to path-through (from your controller to the using method) or use dependency injection to retrieve the HttpContext (via IHttpContextAccessor, which need to be made available before). Then you can use `httpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("showonlykeys")` to fetch the value.

Comment: ps. DNX is a bit outdated and is no longer supported. Update to RTM!